# How to move configuration between grub installs

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I had installed Ubuntu 16 on a mixed environment. 1 HD (SSD) with windows and 1 HD (spinner) with Ubuntu 16 and Data. Fast forward now, I've added an SSD for Ubuntu 18 on a new SSD with a small EFI partition and I'm trying to get rid of the old grub. My Goal is to have the newest HD as boot and be able to pick both ubuntu 18 and Windows 7. The second disk with ubuntu 16 should be visible and mountable so that I'll be able to move away my data from it.

My first attempt was to remove the second disc and try to let Grub on ubuntu 18 to see windows. Unfortunately it did not work, because my Ubuntu 16 install had Grub installed on the filesystem of Ubuntu 16 instead that separately. If I reattach the second HD, I am able to see Ubuntu 16 from Ubuntu 18 and also boot the second HD to see the old Ubuntu still there.

boot-repair is not able to help me. In both cases. It seems that valuable data are still on the second disc and there is no easy way to let the newest grub see it and copy on my new EFI partition somehow.

I'm not sure if it's clear so here are two boot-repair results:

1. hda= old SSD (windows only + data, hdb = new SSD (ubuntu 18)
   http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nnfF5dxqXq/
2. hda = old SSD (windows only + data),hdb=old HDD (ubuntu 16+data) , hdc=new SSD (ubuntu 18)
   http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GdVbRMrCKg

side note: I can't use my windows 7 original CD because the Drive is somehow broken (I hadn't used it in years)

Comment: You cannot. You can dual boot from your UEFI boot menu, f12 or whatever your system uses. Some may require you to turn on/off UEFI boot mode. UEFI and and the now 35 yr old BIOS boot mode are not compatible. Once you start booting in one mode from UEFI, you cannot switch. Or grub only boots other installs in same boot mode. If you really want to dual boot from grub you can reinstall Windows in UEFI mode(conversion from MBR to gpt will erase drive), or convert Ubuntu to BIOS boot. Ubuntu can boot in BIOS mode just by reinstalling grub, but you must first add a 1 or 2MB unformatted bios_grub.

Comment: @oldfred I thought my windows installation was in uefi mode as well. I have a 200mb efi partition on the ubuntu sdd just for that. I can delete it and use it. Where do i get more info on that?

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred the link I provided were already made with the newest boot-repair. Note that I tried also to set the boot location on the new SSD where the EFI partition is. This is the boot info. http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hCSrdMknCd/ (note. right now I have all 3 HD attached and use the bios to start the old HDD to use windows (and the old ubuntu)

Comment: Your sda & sdb drives are MBR(msdos). Windows only boots in BIOS boot mode from MBR partitioned drives and only in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drive. Best to put Windows boot loader in MBR of sda for BIOS boot and boot from UEFI boot menu in legacy/BIOS mode. Otherwise you need to reinstall systems after data backup, all in same boot mode. Grub will only boot other systems installed in same boot mode. And grub only boots working Windows. Since Windows breaks and may turn fast start up back on, you may need to directly boot Windows, so need Windows boot loader in sda.